# tried a example from a c tutorial site kinda got it wrong

Tags: c

I was learning about recursion in C from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_recursion.htm  and I tried the number factorial example.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int i) {
    if (i <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fact(i - 1);
}

int main() {
    int i = 3;
    printf("numb = %d", fact(i));
    return 0;
}
```

After I executed the code it printed 1. I reviewed the code and found that I forgot to multiply var `i` with `fact(i - 1)` at the end of the function. I fixed it and got the correct factorial, but why is `fact(3 - 1)` equal to 1?

Edit

I had a very shallow understanding of recursion when i posted this question,i thought `fact(i-1)` would just execute once and didn't get the meaning of calling the function again in the tutorial and i didn't understand it at first when i read the busybee's answer i think i get it now `fact(3-1)` called `fact(2-1)` value of var `i` is now 1 and  it satisfied the if condition and returned 1. Another question in the correct version where i multiply var `i` with `fact(i-1)` when i change `return 1` to `return 2`  why does it return `12`, from the pattern of `return 1` and `return 2` it seem to multiply `6` result of the function `fact` with the number in return why? i admit i did no research  on what return does and just kinda went with the flow.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your question?

Comment: I've never coded in C, but yes, according to your code, `fact(3-1) = 1`. It the same as coding `fact(2)`, and it returns `1`, since `2-1` (what you function returns) is equal to `1`.

Comment: `fact(3-1)` returned 1 though it should return 2. I found that `fact()` got called again and met the if condition i don't know why it got called again and why `fact(3-1)` didn't  return to main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fact(3 - 1)` returns `1` in your first and erroneous version, because it called `fact()` with `i` with `2`.

This is not less or equal to 1, so `fact()` is called with `2 - 1`. Now this is less or equal to 1, and `1` is returned.

This result is unchanged returned again, and finally once more returned to `main()`.

As a list:

- `main()` calls `fact(3)`.

  - `fact(3)` calls `fact(2)`, because its `i` is 3 and so greater than 1.

    - `fact(2)` calls `fact(1)`, because its `i` is 2 and so greater than 1.

      - `fact(1)` returns `1` to `fact(2)`, because its `i` is less or equal to 1.
    - `fact(2)` returns the `1` returned from `fact(1)` unchanged to `fact(3)`.
  - `fact(3)` returns the `1` returned from `fact(2)` unchanged to `main()`.
- `main()` prints the `1` returned from `fact(3)`.

**Edit:**

When you're in doubt how your functions are called and what they do, use a debugger (best approach) or insert some `printf()` (poor man's debugging, but quite easy), like this:

```c
int fact(int i) {
    printf("fact(%d) begins ...\n", i);
    if (i <= 1) {
        printf("... fact(%d) returns 1 because of %d <= 1\n", i, i);
        return 1;
    }
#if 1 // just temporarily
    printf("... fact(%d) calls fact(%d)\n", i, i - 1);
    int r = fact(i - 1);
    printf("... fact(%d) returns %d\n", i, r);
    return r;
#else
    return fact(i - 1);
#endif
}
```

**Edit 2:**

You might have missed some important things in the lesson on recursive functions.

- Each function has its own set of parameters and local variables.
- In general, a recursively called function does not have any insight in the local variables or parameters of the calling function.
- A recursively called function returns to the calling function. (Some compilers might optimize a "tail call" into a "tail jump", though.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So it kinda looped until the if condition is met.I got another question now why it didn't return `fact(3-1)` to main?

Comment: Well, it **did** return the result of `fact(3 - 1)` to main. The result was `1`.

Comment: I mean when i multiply `i` with `fact(i-1)` it returns 6 which is the factorial of 3,but when i forgot to multiply `i` with `fact(i-1)`, after it does `fact(3-1)` why it doesn't return to main but instead does `fact(2-1)`?

Comment: Hm, I don't get what you mean. `fact(3 - 1)` has to call `fact(2 - 1)` because its `i` is not equal to 1. I'll extend my answer. -- Please look through the list, insert the `printf()`s as suggested, and watch.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have just edited my original question and i hope that you will read it and answer my edited question, and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: OK, then. There is not much to answer, because you did not do a bit to gain some insight. Please insert the `printf()` as shown and follow the output. You might even pretend to be the computer and jot down some arcs and notes on a paper listing of the code, if you desire. You need to do something yourself to understand, our magic pills are in quarantaine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ok i copied your code and executed it,the output 

fact(3) begins ...
... fact(3) calls fact(2)
fact(2) begins ...
... fact(2) calls fact(1)
fact(1) begins ...
... fact(1) returns 1 because of 1 <= 1
... fact(2) returns 1
... fact(3) returns 1
numb = 1

from the output it is clear that at first `fact(3)` begins does `fact(3-1)` and calls `fact(2-1)` and `fact(1)` starts as the value of the var `i` is now 1,the if condition is satisfied and returns 1. i think thats it to this question(?) if there are any problems in my understanding of the output clear it.

Comment: And, did you change the code to return "2" if the condition is satisfied? Do you understand why the result is "12" in that case?

Comment: i think its because its goes through all the process twice? please correct me if im wrong,and i noticed that my formating is hard to read any tips on how to improve my formating?

Comment: Comments are ment for just that, comments. There is nothing we can do to format them further. -- And, no, it does not go twice. Apparently you did not run it. Next try.

Comment: I did run it with your prinf() statements except the `if 1` and it does not go through it twice. I thought you would give the answer but i think you want me to find it myself,my next guess is that 6  the result of `fact(3)` is multiplied by 2 in the return statement.

Comment: You got it. Isn't this a bigger pleasure than if someone told it to you? You will hardly forget it.

Comment: I guess so?, i feel like i was struggling with a nonexistant problem/not important one, Anyways thank you for opening my eyes, i guess i would have just ignored recursion and wouldn't get at this stage without your comments. And another thank you for taking your time to comment and answer my question

Answer (score 3):

To compute the factorial recursively, `i` must be a positive integer. So that either the value of `i` is 0 or 1 the factorial will be 1.

If not, then call the recursive factorial algorithm with `(i - 1)` then multiply the result by `i` and return that value as shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int i)
{
   if (i ==1)
      return 1;

   return fact(i - 1) * i; // You forgot to multiply  i  here
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 3;
    printf("Number = %d", fact(i)); // Displaying the factorial of 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's a lot more helpful to add some explanation what this code does and how it solves the question. Code only answers are generally not accepted.

Comment: @MeanGreen : I make the explanation , sorry a lot

Comment: It's not a big deal :) But the answer is much better now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not the answer i was looking for.thnx for reply anyway.